# How can I bring a window to the foreground in Vista using C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I have a piece of code that brings the window under the cursor to the foreground using  the SetForegroundWindow API for WinXP. I have been testing it for Vista but the API seems to no longer do the job correctly.

AllowSetForeground did not help, my process is a background process.

What can I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8):

Try the following code and see if it works for you:

```
SetWindowPos(WndHandle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
SetWindowPos(WndHandle,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: This does it for me -- and was the only thing (short of calling ShowWindow with MINIMIZE and then ShowWindow with RESTORE) that has the effect of bringing the window the front. Other attempts, including SetForegroundWindow and BringWindowToFront Just-Dont-Work, but This-Approach-Does.

Answer (score 1):

If `SetForegroundWindow()` fails, have you tried setting the window `WS_EX_TOPMOST` and then immediately non top most right after calling `SetForegroundWindow()`?

It might have something to do with people rightfully complaining about applications poping all over the place when you least expect it.

Answer (score 1):

If using MFC, this worked for me in Windows 7 x64:

```
    RECT rc;
    m_pMainWnd->GetWindowRect(&rc);

    int nBoxWidth = rc.left-rc.right;
    int nBoxHeight = rc.bottom-rc.top;
    int nBoxTop = rc.top;
    int nBoxLeft = rc.left;

    SetWindowPos(m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), HWND_TOPMOST,
                    nBoxLeft, nBoxTop, nBoxWidth, nBoxHeight,
                    SWP_NOMOVE || SWP_NOSIZE);
    SetWindowPos(m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd(), HWND_NOTOPMOST,
                    nBoxLeft, nBoxTop, nBoxWidth, nBoxHeight,
                    SWP_SHOWWINDOW || SWP_NOMOVE || SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VOID SwitchToThisWindow(HWND hWnd, BOOL fAltTab);
```

Works on XP to Windows 7 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633553.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately "[This function is not intended for general use. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions of Windows.]" :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting the current thread asleep did it for me, together with setting it to non-topmost before:

```
OS.SetWindowPos(handle, OS.HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, OS.SWP_NOMOVE | OS.SWP_NOSIZE);
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    LOG.error("sleeping thread was interrupted", e);
}
OS.SetWindowPos(handle, OS.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, OS.SWP_NOMOVE | OS.SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Answer (score -2):

Just a warning: there was a public API to do that (SetForegroundWindow), now it does not bring the window in the foreground anymore.

Now the window just flashes.

But this was for a reason. Applications doing that "steal" the focus from the current window (often without a good reason) and can lead to all kind of problems.

So before trying to circumvent the protections put by the OS against this kind of behavior, make sure you will not annoy your users. Ask yourself: "do I really-really have to jump in my user's face, even if my application is in the background?"

Comment: No offense, but personally I dislike answers like this. He wasn't asking for advice on how to design his program, he wanted an answer to a specific technical problem.

Comment: Well, I'm going to stick up for this answer! One of the most helpful things an answer can do is to show the original questioner that perhaps the question they're asking indicates they're doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Agreed.  The answer isn't off topic and is relevant :)

Comment: I agree with @korona. This should be a comment instead, because it does not answer the question ("How...") at all. (As a comment, I also agree with @Mihai Nita)

Answer (score -4):

use windows powertoys tweakui program to change the state of permission for focus.

select "general" then "focus" and then de-check the box allowing other programs to take focus.

This works when everyones suggestions seem not to work, (they actually all do).

microsoft in thier infinate wisdom decided that the response from calls to setforegrondwindow etc etc will now be null.

they didn't bother to say tjat you can still get back to original by tweakui!!!!

enjoy.....