# visual studio 2010 setup project - message box in custom actions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project, custom-action

I'm using a `MessageBox.Show` method inside a Custom Action. The window goes to back though. Is there any way to bring it to front/focus?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Vista applications can no longer bring their windows on top of the Z order. Instead, the application window is shown in the background and its taskbar icon flashes.

If you want to show the window on top of the Z order, you can try this approach: [How can I bring a window to the foreground in Vista using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534241/how-can-i-bring-a-window-to-the-foreground-in-vista-using-c)